# The loops for this array works but I still get an Compiler Error? Debug Error Run-Time Check Failure #2 - S

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Hey guys so I just started working with arrays.

Could someone shed some light on this topic please. This was I created, I thought it made sense but I must be missing something.
I get an Debug Error  Run-Time Check Failure #2 - S

Type of the Error is the following: **Debug Error Run-Time Check Failure #2 - S**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <climits>


//Prototypes:
int lowestAmount(int[]);
int highestAmount(int[]);



using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int AMOUNT = 9;

    int values[AMOUNT];
    int lowest, highest;

    cout << "Please Insert 10 Numbers of your Choice: ";
    cin >> values[0] >> values[1] >> values[2] >> values[3] >>
        values[4] >> values[5] >> values[6] >> values[7] >>
        values[8] >> values[9];
    cout << endl;
    lowest = lowestAmount(values);
    highest = highestAmount(values);

    cout << "/tThe Lowest out of all of them is: " << lowest <<
        endl;
    cout << "/tThe Highest out of all of them is: " << highest << endl ;


    return 0;
}



int lowestAmount(int val[]) {

    int lowest = INT_MAX;
    int count = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (val[i] < lowest)
            lowest = val[i];
    }

    return lowest;
}

int highestAmount(int val[]) {
    int highest = INT_MIN;
    int count = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (val[i] > highest)
            highest = val[i];
    }
    return highest;
}
```

The code sort of works but not correctly all the time, and I can't figure out what I did wrong? I though I had the logic down??? Could someone shed some light???

Comment: Hi! Your code [doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: It, sort of does, but I get an error that says.

Debug error

Runtime Check Failure #2 - S

Comment: I incremented the count var in both functions by 1 so instead of 9 I put 10 and I still get the Error???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indices start at zero, which means that the last index is the amount of elements minus one. You want the user to input 10 numbers, and you do read `vales[0]` up to `values[9]` but your array doesn't have the room for it.

```
const int AMOUNT = 9;

int values[AMOUNT];
```

That means you declare an array big enough for 9 elements, not 10. `AMOUNT` needs to be 10.

C++ does not automatically do bounds checking. This means that if you write outside of an array, you are going to get unpredictable behaviour, and you cannot even rely on the program always crashing.

There's also a bug in both your higher/lower functions that ignores the last element even as it stands now. Once you fix the array to be for 10 elements, you need to loop until `i < 10` after that.

Also in the future, you will get better help by posting **specifically** what does not work, meaning you should show compiler / debugger errors, not just your code.

Comment: Does the array when it starts, start at 0? so from 0-9 is 10 ??? I replaced the amount from 9 to 10 and it worked!! However I'm confused? However does incrementing it to 10 work like being that an array starts at 0 and goes to 9 being that 0 to 9 is a total of 10 values??

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry, I'm new to the community, Next time I'll make sure to insert the error in the post as well Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it starts at 0, and 0 to 9 means there are ten places. Count on your fingers :) This is a very common source of confusion when first learning arrays. But remember that array indexes start at 0 and so the last element is size - 1. In a ten-element array, the last one has index 9.

Comment: I see now, So it goes up to the last number set and stops, it doesn't actually counts it. So if I put 10 it sees 10 and stops. Cool awesome. Thank you.